# unstack dataframe with relevant columns only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe:

```
data = {'year': [2010, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2011, 2012, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013],
            'store_number': ['1944', '1945', '1946', '1947', '1948', '1949', '1947', '1948', '1949', '1947'],
            'retailer_name': ['Walmart','Walmart', 'CRV', 'CRV', 'CRV', 'Walmart', 'Walmart', 'CRV', 'CRV', 'CRV'],
            'product': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c'],
            'amount': [5, 5, 8, 6, 1, 5, 10, 6, 12, 11],
            'vat': [0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.6, 0.1, 0.5, 0.10, 0.6, 0.12, 0.11]}

    stores = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['retailer_name', 'store_number', 'year', 'product', 'amount', 'vat'])
    stores.set_index(['retailer_name', 'store_number', 'year', 'product'], inplace=True)
    df = stores.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2, 3]).sum().unstack('product')
    mask = pd.IndexSlice['amount', :]
    df.loc[:, mask] = df.loc[:, mask].fillna(0)
```

And I get following output:

```
                                amount           vat           
product                              a   b   c     a    b     c
retailer_name store_number year                                
CRV           1946         2011      8   0   0  0.80  NaN   NaN
              1947         2012      6   0   0  0.60  NaN   NaN
                           2013      0   0  11   NaN  NaN  0.11
              1948         2011      6   1   0  0.60  0.1   NaN
              1949         2012     12   0   0  0.12  NaN   NaN
Walmart       1944         2010      5   0   0  0.50  NaN   NaN
              1945         2010      0   5   0   NaN  0.5   NaN
              1947         2010      0  10   0   NaN  0.1   NaN
              1949         2012      5   0   0  0.50  NaN   NaN
```

I dont need those `vat` columns in my final result, how I can remove them from my `unstack`ing ?

Comment: When I run your code I don't see the `vat` columns

Comment: @EdChum I get them

Comment: I'm running version 0.18.1 what version of pandas are you running

Comment: @ EdChum my mistake I edited the post, sorry.

Comment: You could just select in the initial call here `df = stores.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2, 3]).sum().unstack('product')['amount']`

Comment: @ EdChum, thanks exactly what I needed.

Comment: The thing is your code merely only calls `fillna` on your mask, you don't restrict the selection of your df to just the mask which is a different thing entirely, this is why you don't see the `NaN` values for 'vat' being filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me works:

```
df = stores.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2, 3]).sum().unstack('product')

df = df['amount'].fillna(0)
print (df)
product                             a     b     c
retailer_name store_number year                  
CRV           1946         2011   8.0   0.0   0.0
              1947         2012   6.0   0.0   0.0
                           2013   0.0   0.0  11.0
              1948         2011   6.0   1.0   0.0
              1949         2012  12.0   0.0   0.0
Walmart       1944         2010   5.0   0.0   0.0
              1945         2010   0.0   5.0   0.0
              1947         2010   0.0  10.0   0.0
              1949         2012   5.0   0.0   0.0
```

All together:

```
df = stores.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2, 3]).sum().unstack('product')['amount'].fillna(0)
print (df)

product                             a     b     c
retailer_name store_number year                  
CRV           1946         2011   8.0   0.0   0.0
              1947         2012   6.0   0.0   0.0
                           2013   0.0   0.0  11.0
              1948         2011   6.0   1.0   0.0
              1949         2012  12.0   0.0   0.0
Walmart       1944         2010   5.0   0.0   0.0
              1945         2010   0.0   5.0   0.0
              1947         2010   0.0  10.0   0.0
              1949         2012   5.0   0.0   0.0
```

Another solution is select column `amount` for [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df = stores.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2, 3])['amount'].sum().unstack('product').fillna(0)
print (df)
product                             a     b     c
retailer_name store_number year                  
CRV           1946         2011   8.0   0.0   0.0
              1947         2012   6.0   0.0   0.0
                           2013   0.0   0.0  11.0
              1948         2011   6.0   1.0   0.0
              1949         2012  12.0   0.0   0.0
Walmart       1944         2010   5.0   0.0   0.0
              1945         2010   0.0   5.0   0.0
              1947         2010   0.0  10.0   0.0
              1949         2012   5.0   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Glad can help you!